# ftp username and password automated in shell script

Tags: shell

I want to create *.sh file*

```
// Tried to connect to ftp server
ftp name_of_server   
 //input user name
username
 //input password
password
```

link given below
https://github.com/prokid221/shell-programing.git

Instead of login, it again asked to enter username and password.
Can any one help with this problem?

Comment: Use `expect` for this sort of thing.

Comment: If you are planning to login to ftp website, you can try `ftp://username:password@hostname/`. This will not work on  `FTP server` though

Answer (score 2):

If you only need file transfers, you could use curl.

download a file:

```
curl -O -u user:password ftp://example.com/some-file
```

upload a file:

```
curl -T some-file -u user:password ftp://example.com
```

Note: This method may result in your credentials being saved in your command history.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to look at your `ftp` command manual. It probably provides command line flags or can use environment variables to allow you to specify username and password.

If there is no such thing, an alternate way is to feed `ftp` standard input. I guess this is what you try to do, but instead here is what your script does:

1. Run `ftp` and wait for the command to return. That's where `ftp` asks about username.
2. Once `ftp` returned, run a command named after the username. There is probably no command of that name so it will complain about it.
3. Then, run a command named after the password. It will fail too, but depending on the special characters in the password, it could become a disaster :-)

So, to really feed stdin, you can use printf(1):

```
printf "username\npassword\n" | ftp name_of_website
```

**Edit**: Another way I forgot is to put those informations in the URL: `ftp://username:password@name_of_website`.

Comment: using terminal in mac i can login into my ftp server... but i created a .sh file containing same commands ..... while executing that .sh file, again it is asking to enter username and pasword

Comment: You can't put what you typed in a script and hope it will just work: `ftp name_of_website` is read and interpreted by your shell, while `username` and `password` are read by `ftp`. However, if you put what you typed in a shell script as is, everything is interpreted by the shell: it doesn't know what to do with this username/password. But even before that, `ftp` still expects username/password on its input.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='your.ftp.server.net'
USER='yourid'
PASSWD='yourpw'
FILE='file.txt'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
#put $FILE
#quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

If you want to provide hostname from outside the script as commandline, then you can use,
`HOST = $1`  ,
So if you scriptname is `serverftp.sh`, you would provide hostname as;
`serverftp.sh <ftp_server_name>`

Comment: sh /Users/CGC/Desktop/help.sh 
Connected to prokid221.my3gb.com.
220 server ready - login please
331 password required
230 login accepted
/Users/CGC/Desktop/help.sh: line 19:  1011 Segmentation fault: 11  ftp -n $HOST  <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
#put $FILE
#quit
END_SCRIPT
This is the output found on my screen

Comment: Is there an option to  using ssh or scp ? It is more robust and is more script friendly. There are many examples available on SO.

Comment: i found your ans quit satisfiying but the problem  is it exits after executing the code ... is there any way that code does not quit

Comment: Comment out `exit 0` to `#exit 0` and try

Comment: Try: `ftp -in <your_ftp_server> <<END_SCRIPT`
`$user $USERNAME $PASSWORD`
`binary`
`SCRIPTEND`  .. and see if it works. Else you will need to use `expect`

Answer (score 0):

how about use `expect` in shell script?

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVER="example.com"
ID="toor"
PASSWD="secret"

expect <<EOF 
    spawn ftp $SERVER 
    expect ": "
    send "$ID\r"
    expect "Password:"
    send "$PASSWD\r"
    expect "ftp>"
    send "ls\r
    expect "ftp>"
    send "quit\r
    interact
EOF
```